# Shake to undo issue ios Safari

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, vue.js, safari

I'm putting together a webapp game using ios safari and you start by filling out a form in vuejs but after that, the form is replaced with a new vuejs screen when the game is started. During the game however, if people shake their phones, it is prompting them to undo / redo their typing which wouldn't even be possible as there isn't even a form on the page anymore.

Any idea on how to stop / remove this behavior? I've tried tapping into the event listener 'devicemotion' but that didn't do anything

Here's an example of the devicemotion script i've tried

```
window.addEventListener('devicemotion', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```